# Finding a spanning tree using exactly k red edges in a graph with edges colored by red/blue in linear time.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

So we have a graph $G$ with its edges colored by red and blue. we are asked to find a deterministic linear time algorithm that given a parameter $K$ finds a spanning tree of G using exactly $K$ red edges or says non exists otherwise.

so what we have done so far is:

Let every red edge have weight of $-1$ and every blue edge have weight of $0$

use an algorithm that finds a minimum spanning tree in linear time. so we have a spanning tree $T$ that its weight is minimal, meaning we used as much red edges as we can because red edges will only decrease the weight.

if there are less than $K$ red edges in $T$, we return that it is impossible to find one.

now if there are exactly $K$ red edges we are done.

IF there are more than $K$ red edges we need to replace them with blue ones.

and here is our problem, how do we do that in linear time?

every blue edge added will indeed create a cycle. so removing one red edge from the cycle will work but how can we ensue linearity in this way?.. is this even a good approach? any leads will be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363403/spanning-tree-with-exactly-k-colored-edges

Comment: It has to do with edge contraction, plus what you gave me isn't linear

Comment: The weighted spanning trees can be built in linear time with a BFS or DFS and appropriate flag values being assigned to the nodes (basically whether they are included or not).  The 2nd part is doable in linear time if the edges are given flags that say whether or not they are in a given spanning tree, and edge traversal is linear in the number of edges.

Comment: adding an edge and then finding the cycle it created and all that in a loop running on edges...that's not linear.